# The current context for id does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get hold a session from date picker?

For all my textbox, I hold it using :

```
 Session["location"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
 Session["time"] = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;
 Session["day"] = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text;  
 Session["IsChauffeurUsed"] = DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text;
```

But for my text box date picker, when I write the code

```
 Session["date"] = datepicker.Text;
```

It gives me an error, the current context does not exist.
The date picker text box is :

```
<div class="demo"><p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p></div>
```

Hope you can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `runat=server` attribute to convert html tag to Html server control.

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="datepicker">
```

and use `value` attribute because it is now ASP.NET Web Server control.

```
Session["date"] = datepicker.Value;
```

Edit: This works perfectly on my side.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#datePicker").datepicker();
            $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="datePicker" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: it is working, but my date picker doesnt pop up after I changed the code. Can u tell me why?

Comment: Is this (datepicker) jQuery UI widget?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Maybe the tag is not closed like this: '<input type="text" runat="server" id="datepicker" />'

Comment: Open the *Web Console* (in webbrowser) and show us what exceptions/errors are there.

Comment: Shouldn't the one line be $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').attachDatepicker();

Comment: Thank you @AVD!!!!!! You saved me!!!!! U such a good helper! Thank you! You have no idea, hoe long i've spent my time doing this part! Thank you. U just make my day!