# Jquery ui in CDN

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downloading jQuery CSS from Google's CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/downloading-jquery-css-from-googles-cdn)

Is anyone here knows how to use content delivery network  (Google) for css jquery datepicker? Is that possible? Here is the css.

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/sunny/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

like for jquery and jquery ui i used:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at your previous thread and my answer [<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" />](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170388/the-current-context-for-id-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JQuery UI Blog](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/08/jquery-ui-1-8-23/) it looks like you can grab it here:

- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css